# GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column when attempting to order by multiple records in relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, pdo

**Introduction**

So the idea is that I have a `players` table, all we need to know about this table is that it has an `id` and `username` fields.

I also have a `financials` table, all we need to know about this table is that it references the `players` table through the `player_id` foreign key. It also has another two fields, `staked` and `won`.

A `player` can have many `financials`. So for example, a player could have 5 `financials` records associated with themselves.

**The issue**

I'm attempting to return a list of players which are sorted by their financial records. So for example, I'd like to retrieve the players who have made the most net revenue for the company. Here is a query I have written against Laravel's 
Query Builder (`Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`).

```
    DB::table('financials AS f')
        ->select(['*', DB::raw('SUM(staked - (won)) AS net_revenue')])
        ->join('players AS p', function ($join) use ($param) {
            $join->on('f.player_id', '=', 'p.id')
                ->where('p.id', 'like', '%' . $param . '%')
                ->orWhere('p.username', 'like', '%' . $param . '%');
            })
        ->orderBy('net_revenue')
        ->groupBy(['f.id'])
        ->paginate($perPage);
```

**The Error**

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #9 of
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 
'master.p.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY 
clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select 
*, SUM(staked - (won)) AS net_revenue from `financials` as `f` inner join 
`players` as `p` on `f`.`player_id` = `p`.`id` and `p`.`id` like %% or 
`p`.`username` like %% group by `f`.`id` order by `net_revenue` asc limit 15 
offset 0)
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction to fixing this issue? I'd greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT (08/06/2017):**

```
      $query = DB::table('financials AS f1')
      ->select(['f1.id', 'f1.plays', 'f1.game_id', 'f1.staked', 'f1.won', 'f1.player_id', 'f1.date', 'f1.type', DB::raw('SUM(f1.staked - (f1.won)) AS net_revenue')])
      ->leftJoin('financials AS f2', 'f1.player_id', '=', 'f2.player_id')
      ->groupBy(['f1.id', 'f1.player_id', 'f1.game_id'])
      ->orderBy($orderBy)
      ->paginate($perPage);
```

So my query now looks like this, and it works, it generates the net_revenue for each record. However it returns me multiple records for the same player_id.

To elaborate, if I have two records for the same player, it calculates the net_revenue for both records and orders them from highest to lowest, however what I want is only a single record for the player containing the calculation of all net_revenue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order by as SUM(staked - (won)) instead of the field name.

Comment: It say's unknown column `SUM(staked - (won))`

Comment: Actually, it's the same error with the group by now.

Comment: I think you are selecting * which is wrong, you should select only the group by column and the aggregate expression.. It is the issue with select column not the order by clause.

Comment: I have since changed the query, please see the edited question above.